# Why a syntax error in the Update statement?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

```
$uploadDate = date("Y-m-d"); 
$sql = "INSERT into book (img_path, title, author, publisher, description, quantity, category, publish_date, upload_id, isbn, sku) values('$book_name', '$bookTitle', '$bookAuthor', '$bookPublisher', '$bookDescription', $bookStock, '$category', '$uploadDate', '$uploadID', '$isbn', '$sku');";
$statusAccept = 'Book Published';
$sql .= "UPDATE upload SET status = '$statusAccept' AND file = '$filename' WHERE no = '$uploadID'";
// Execute multi query
if (mysqli_multi_query($conn,$sql)) {
    do {
        // Store first result set
        if ($result=mysqli_store_result($con)) {
        // Fetch one and one row
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
                echo "New record created successfully <br/>";
            }
            // Free result set
            mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
    }
    while (mysqli_next_result($con));
}
```

I got problem of using `mysqi_multi_query()` from the example on w3schools, the first query successfully inserted but the second query successfully updated with wrong value of status. The status become string of number 0 ("0") instead of string from variable `$statusAccept`. Right now, I tried to redirect into another PHP file and update the status again from the string number of zero into the string from variable that desired before.

Comment: You're vulnerable to SQL Injection Attacks with that code. You should use prepared statements

Comment: I think update multiple column is using `,` as separator, not using `AND`

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you checked whether MySQL returns any error code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second query is incorrect:

```
UPDATE upload SET status = '$statusAccept' AND file = '$filename' WHERE no = '$uploadID'
```

It should be:

```
UPDATE upload SET status = '$statusAccept', file = '$filename' WHERE no = '$uploadID'
```

Read more about [UPDATE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html).

And do not forget to use **[Prepared Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.html)**.